# HTML 5 wait for drawImage to finish in a Vue SPA

Tags: html, vue.js, canvas, drawimage

I have been trying to debug something for a week and I now suspect the problem is that the `drawImage` function does not have time to finish. I have a for loop that composes a canvas element by stitching together two different canvas elements and then add that `composedCanvas` as a frame to a [GIF.js](https://github.com/jnordberg/gif.js) object. The problem I keep running into is that the bottom stitched canvas does not appear or partially appears (the picture below started to draw but did not finish) in my output GIF file. My question is how do I ensure synchronous execution of `drawImage` in the context of a Vue SPA method. I have experimented with `Promise`, but I have not gotten it to work. Can anyone explain and help me with this, please?

EDIT : I have tried wrapping my `drawImage` in a promise and `await` but it raised type errors.

[image]

Comment: Have you played around with async and await functions ?

Comment: Yes sir. I tried wrapping everything in promises but to no effect so far, except errors about not expecting promises. Also `drawImage` does not fire events such as renderComplete or loaded so I can not wait for them in such a manner.

Comment: Can you provide your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by properly wrapping the `drawImage` step in a separate method and inside a promise the proper way. See the code below for an example of two `methods` that were the culprits but are now fixed.

```js
async composeCanvas( gif , timeStep , visibleLayers , delayInput) {
    const mapCnv = this.getMapCanvas();
    await this.updateInfoCanvas( timeStep )
    const numberVisibleLayers = visibleLayers.length;
    const composedCnv = await this.stitchCanvases( mapCnv , numberVisibleLayers );
    gif.addFrame(composedCnv, {copy:false, delay: delayInput});
},
async stitchCanvases( mapCanvas , numberVisibleLayers ) {
    return new Promise(( resolve ) => {
        var composedCnv = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = composedCnv.getContext('2d');
        var ctx_w = mapCanvas.width;
        var ctx_h = mapCanvas.height + ((numberVisibleLayers - 1) * 30) + 40;
        
        composedCnv.width = ctx_w;
        composedCnv.height = ctx_h;

        [
            {
                cnv: mapCanvas,
                y: 0
            },
            {
                cnv: this.infoCanvas,
                y: mapCanvas.height
            }
        ].forEach( ( n ) => {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.drawImage(n.cnv, 0, n.y, ctx_w, n.cnv.height);
        });

        resolve(composedCnv)
    })
}
```